# Is <sup></sup> possible in Crystal Reports VS 2008?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a requirement to show Date as 'Wednesday October 27<sup>th</sup>, 2012' (the 'th' should be super scripted).  Is is possible in Crystal Reports of VS 2008?

I have used formula field with Text Interpretation set to "HTML Text", but still I didn't get the solution.  Can anyone suggest me the way?

Thanks, Rakesh.